# Why Thumbnail caurosel is not working on latest bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a thumbnail carousel which is having 4 columns and running one after another. And it is running fine on old bootstrap version.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But when I am using the latest version of bootstrap, it is not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Please guide or help me to run this carousel on new version too.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-centered">

            <div id="ThumbnailCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2500">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="carousel-col">
                            <div class="block red img-responsive"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carousel-col">
                            <div class="block green img-responsive"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carousel-col">
                            <div class="block blue img-responsive"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="carousel-col">
                            <div class="block yellow img-responsive"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <div class="left carousel-control">
                    <a href="#ThumbnailCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="right carousel-control">
                    <a href="#ThumbnailCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also used media query for the responsiveness of the carousel.

```
.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-control { 
    width: 8%;
    width: 0px;
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right { 
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 32px; 
    background-image: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-control > a > span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 29px !important;
}

.carousel-col { 
    position: relative; 
    min-height: 1px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    float: left;
 }

 .active > div { display:none; }
 .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

/*xs*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 50%; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}

/*sm*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -50%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 50%; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}

/*md*/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -33%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 33%; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div { display:block; }
}

/*lg*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
  .carousel-inner .active.right{ left:  25%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev            { left: -25%; }
  .carousel-col                { width: 25%; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
  .active > div:first-child + div + div { display:block; }
    .active > div:first-child + div + div + div { display:block; }
}

.block {
    width: 330px;
    height: 230px;
}

.red {background: red;}

.blue {background: blue;}

.green {background: green;}

.yellow {background: yellow;}
```

following is the javascript which i have used

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: Just FYI the latest version of Bootstrap is 4.0, but that will likely cause you even more problems

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sir is there is any solution for that?

Comment: @j08691 Sir in console its not showing any error..... please help me what else i can do?